# IPython check if the user running a script is the root user (Linux)

Tags: linux, root, ipython

What is the right way to have an IPython script check to see if the user is currently root?

Here's how I do it in bash scripts:

```
if [ $(id -u) != "0" ];then
   echo "This script must be run as root."
   exit 1
fi
```

Is there a better way than using "!id" or "!whoami"?

Comment: Can you use `geteuid()` in the `os` module?

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need to be root for? There may be a cleaner way than running the entire script

Comment: @Daenyth - it is an installation script that does a bunch of things. So the easiest way is to run it as root. But I am also interested in knowing how to execute commands as sudo in iPhython. (Today is the first day I have ever tried iPython.)

Comment: If it's an installation script the best practice is not to use one, and instead package your software for the target distro's package manager. Making just an rpm and a deb gets you a long long way.

Comment: I'm not interested in packaging my software. I am interested in knowing the answer to my question, tho. ;-)

Comment: @bernie: yes, os.geteuid() works as does ! id -u. I suppose I'll use one of those. Thanks.

Comment: @bernie: supply and answer and I'll accept it. I used your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: you're most welcome. answer supplied. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *nix OSs there is [`geteuid()` in the `os` module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.geteuid).